# Local bukkit server not detecting new plugin

Tags: eclipse, bukkit

I made a simple plugin with one command based on the tutorial on http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial . I can compile it to a jar file just fine by using Run As -> Maven Install. The only problem I had was I got this error message that said "tools.jar" not found but I fixed it by manually adding it in the JDK overview window. But when I add the plugin file to my plugins folder, it apparently won't load on my server. If I call plugin, it doesn't show up either, but others do. Here's the code I get when launching the server (couldn't copy): http://pastebin.com/s2ig3ngN

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution: Instead of 2, i accidentally put 3 spaces per indent on the plugin.yml file. Changing this fixed it and my plugin now loads properly.